# Conflict between project and facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio

i have added facebook sdk on my project in android studio. Everything works fine, but there is a conflict between my project sources and facebook.. the "loading" message and the close icon (X black button) are showing wrong, and the more strange is that are appearing with my project resources.

And to be more strange, the project always are getting the string in the "x" positon..

Example:

```
<string name="string_teste_01">test 01</string>
<string name="string_teste_02">test 02</string>
```

in this case, the "loading" message are actually showing "test 02".. if i put one more string like this:

```
<string name="string_teste_01">test 01</string>
<string name="string_teste_03">test 03</string>
<string name="string_teste_02">test 02</string>
```

the "loading" message will show as "test 03"

the same occurs for the close icon.

[ "loading" exaple that i was talking ] 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/750TRl.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're not using the same names as the facebook resources (you can look inside the FacebookSDK project's res directory to see what names are used - but they should be namespaced to avoid clashes).

You may need to do a clean/rebuild when you add new resources, especially when you're including libraries that also have resources. This is because the build process generates an R.java file which translates all the names into integer constants, and when you add a new resource without doing a clean/rebuild, the new integer that's generated for your project's R file could clash with the FacebookSDK's R file.

Comment: yes, i'm not using the same name, and i did an clear/rebuild but without sucess. I don't know if i did the correctly link with my app and facebook.. i just added the "facebook..\bin\classes" folder on library options, and added this library on my project with "compile" option..  everything looks fine, he open my request to facebook's api but mess up the icon and the message..

Comment: No, you need to explicitly add the Facebook SDK as an Android Library, otherwise the Android build system will not build the right R files.